# Why do the label locations in the Print Composer differ from the pdf?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

When I set up labels in my drawing and view them in the print composer they look the way I want them to. However, when I look at the resulting pdf, it looks as though the labels have shifted on me.

My print composer map is controlled by an atlas. The labels I have denoted in the images below are as follows. Labels 1 and 2 have Not been manually placed and are labeled off the line. Labels 3 and 4 Have been manually placed (controlled by the data defined x/y fields), but are also labeled off the line. As you can see in the PDF Print image, labels 2 and 4 look shifted to the left and label 2 also looks have to shifted slightly down as well. Labels 1 and 3 look to be pretty much where I had them in the drawing, but they too seem to shift ever so slightly.

And the location of where the labels look to move to are not always the same from what I have seen. They seem to shift in all directions.

What I have tried:
Locking layers in the print composer.
Adjusted the DPI.
Exporting as image and straight to the printer (same result).
Print as raster.

[image: Shifting Labels]

Has anyone else experienced this before? And if so, do you have a remedy? I am currently using v. 2.16.2